# How to set a default value to form input along with placeholder? ([HTML] or [CSS])

Tags: html, css

Is there any attribute for `<input>` such that I can show `placeholder` while also using the default value set?

If we use `value='10' placeholder='Input a number'` then default value is set but placeholder isn't shown the default value takes its place.

If we use just the `placeholder` then default value can't be set.

Is there to set default value while showing the placeholder too?

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800328/show-placeholder-instead-of-the-default-value-in-html-form) has many such questions but only jQuery and JavaScript

My demo code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var num1, num2;

  num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = '<br>num1 = ' + num1 + '<br>num2 = ' + num2;

  return false;
}
```

```css
body {text-align: center}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
  This doesn't have default value hence placeholder is shown.<br>
  <input class="input" type="number" placeholder="Enter a Number..." id='num1'><br><br> This has value hence placeholder is shown.<br>
  <input class="input" type="number" value='10' placeholder="Enter a number..." id='num2'><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value='submit'>
</form>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Any pure HTML or CSS way of setting the default value??

Comment: Since the placeholder is usually shown in the same position as the value, that would not make much sense to begin with.

Comment: And the purpose of a placeholder is rather to show an example value, _not_ to give instructions that should be placed elsewhere to begin with. “Enter a Number” is not a _good_ placeholder here; _if_ any such extra instruction is necessary, it should be placed outside of the input field in the first place.

Comment: Though question is old but I think you can use one other trick and that is use `title` attribute on input field. It is useful if you can not place labels for input especially in large forms. It shows when user hover on field.